# Task Scheduler isn't opening web page

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I was asked to write a script that updates our database every hour.  It's hosted on our website and updates the database every time the page is visited.  I used Windows Task Scheduler to control the automation part of this process.  I know for a fact that the code involved in updating the database is correct, but now I'm beginning to question whether or not my .bat file is right.  This all started happening once I started another script that does the same thing for another web page.  This is the first .bat file:

```
taskkill.exe /f /im iexplore.exe
start http://website.com/scriptA.php
```

The second consists of this:

```
::taskkill.exe /f /im iexplore.exe
start http://website.com/scriptB.php
```

I'm aware of master-slave database replication but since that's an automatic process that runs constantly whenever the database is updated, we decided against using it because we only want these scripts to run at set intervals.  The first file is set to run every hour starting at 9:45 in the morning, so I've verified that before the second script was added, the database would show a "last updated" timestamp of X:45 (where X is the current hour).  The second file runs every four hours starting at noon, and I also verified that it shows a "last updated" timestamp of X:00.

What is causing this?  I can't waste time constantly checking to see whether or not the database is getting updated properly, and some of our inventory information relies on these databases.  If it's worth anything, the scripts are hosted on the same server, which is the same machine I'm using the scheduler on.

Answer (score 0):

First line of second script does nothing. It is ILLEGAL code. You turned it into a label of `:`. Some people believe it is a comment, but they are wrong. It is only a label - an illegal one at that.